# MySQL Index Structure: multiple or single index?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

I have question about database optimizing, indexing. I have table that called "projects" and i will execute queries like this:

**Ordering Queries**

SELECT * FROM projects WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY created

SELECT * FROM projects WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY project_deadtime

SELECT * FROM projects WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY project_allowedtime

**My Table Stucture Like This**

id   int(11)  NO  PRI   NULL  auto_increment
employer_id  int(11)  NO  MUL  NULL
project_title  varchar(100)  NO  MUL  NULL
project_description  text  NO     NULL
project_budget  int(11)  NO     NULL
project_allowedtime  int(11)  NO     NULL
project_deadtime  date  NO     NULL
created  datetime  NO  MUL  NULL
active  tinyint(1)  NO  MUL  NULL

Which columns should i create index and how(single or multiple column index ?). For example should i use active-created & active-project_deadtime & active-project_allowedtime multiple indexes or single active index is enough ?  Thanks

**EDIT: projects table will have maximum 1000-2000 rows. SELECT queries performance is important and about %90 of projects is active.**

Comment: Roughly how many rows will your table maximum have? Roughly what is the maximum number of active projects will there be at any one time?

Comment: projects table will have maximum 1000-2000 rows. SELECT queries performance is important and about %90 of projects is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which queries will be used most often? How many rows will there be? Which queries need to be fastest? Do you run more `SELECT`s or more `INSERT`s? There are a lot of considerations in tuning performance of a database.

Based only on what you've posted, you're using the following columns only:

1. active
2. created
3. project_deadtime
4. project_allowedtime

An index solely on `active` would do little good — it would probably narrow the results down to about half.

The other columns are each potential indices. If you're not as concerned with the performance of `INSERT`s as the performance of `SELECT`s, I'd say index all three, giving priority to the column likely to narrow down a query to the fewest rows:

1. (created, active)
2. (project_deadtime, active)
3. (project_allowedtime, active)

This will allow MySQL to use the index if only the first column is used (e.g., if only `created` is needed) **or** if both columns are used (to narrow results even further).

Comment: projects table will have maximum 1000-2000 rows. SELECT queries performance is important and about %90 of projects is active.

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider the selectivity of the active index.

- If a very small number of your projects are active at any time:

  ```
  (active)
  ```
- If only a relatively small number of your projects are active at any time but the table is very large:

  ```
  (active, created)
  (active, project_deadtime)
  (active, project_allowedtime)
  ```
- If a large proportion of projects can be active at the same time:

  ```
  (created)
  (project_deadtime)
  (project_allowedtime)
  ```

**Update**: based on the new information you provided, I would go with the last option. Though with such a small table the sorting should be close to instant even without an index. Another alternative is to modify the third option to be a covering index.